# NodeJS Store Module Function Result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm trying to get Two-Factor Authentication working with my first proper NodeJS project I'm using to learn and get used to Node.

I have this function with returns the correct values from `data_url` however when I place it in a variable and return `data_url` it comes back as 'undefined'

What works:

```
QRCode.toDataURL(user.tempSecret.otpauth_url, function (err, data_url) {
    console.log(data_url);
});
```

What doesn't work:

```
let thisQR = QRCode.toDataURL(user.tempSecret.otpauth_url, function (err, data_url) {
    return data_url;
});

console.log(thisQR);
```

I need to be able to store this in a variable so I can pass it into my render function and pass it through to the template.

Any help & guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to presume that QRCode.toDataURL is not asynchronous. Based on this assumption, your problem is scoping. You're returning data_url to the anonymous function and not to QRCode.toDataURL.

So again, assuming that this is not an asynchronous function, this will work for you:

```
    let thisQR;
    QRCode.toDataURL(user.tempSecret.otpauth_url, function (err, data_url) {
        thisQR = data_url;
    });
```

If that does not work, then you're dealing with an asynchronous function. Your problem, in this case is that you're trying to console.log "thisQR" before the function is finished processing the request. This link will help you understand asynchronous programming, and what you're doing incorrectly. https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

===========================================================================

Edit to address the comment by OP:

```
function (err, data_url) {
            thisQR = data_url;
        });
```

Above is your callback function. Currently it's an anonymous function (it has no name), but we could give it a name, then do something with the data_url if you wanted. So like this:

```
function doSomethingWithQRCode(err, data_url){
    console.log(data_url);
}

QRCode.toDataURL(user.tempSecret.otpauth_url, doSomethingWithQRCode);
```

Values returned with asynchronous callback function's are limited to the functions scope. So if you want to use those values, you'll have to call the function using those values, inside of the callback function:

```
function doSomethingWithQRCode(err, data_url){
    useQRCode(data_url)
}

QRCode.toDataURL(user.tempSecret.otpauth_url, doSomethingWithQRCode);
```

There are some ways around this depending on your program, but typically this is your best approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and description/link.

as I understand it, I need to make a callback function to get the result when it's ready?

I could do something like `thisFunction(thisCallback);` normally but the fact it's a module's function (QRCode.toDataURL) using a function inside kinda confuses me.

Comment: I've updated my answer, to hopefully address your comment.

Comment: The edited snippets above work to the extent that they print to console perfectly fine, though the first time it logs out it's 'undefined' which might be a problem for what I'm actually trying to achieve?

I'm wanting the returned result to be store in the following object so It can be printed out in my template EJS file

`res.render('twoFactor', {
    title: 'twoFactor',
    image: codeToGetURL
  });`

How'd you go about passing the returned data from an async function to the javascript object without it passing the 'undefined' value it gives first?

Comment: Getting undefined might indicate that some error is occurring. Add some error handling just in case (i.e. `if (err) { throw err; }`). That should bring more clarity to why the `undefined` is occurring. It could be that you're accidentally calling the function twice.

For the `res.render` portion, you can either pass the `res` object through to the result, or use a callback to return the result to `res`'s scope.

P.S. look into promises. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise. They're much cleaner than conventional callbacks.